# Delete audio file from documents directory error

Tags: avaudioplayer

When I try to delete an audio file (.caf) from the documents directory i get that error:

Could not delete file -:The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 4.)

I do the same with images and that is working, so the way I do it should be correct. Anyone knows what that error means?

My guess is that it has something to do with AVAudioPlayer? Do I need to kinda "close it" before to be able to delete or something?!

Thx

Comment: I found out myself. I used a string in the delete method instead of an url.

Answer (score 0):

Error 4 seems to be NSNoSuchFileError - https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Constants/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSFileNoSuchFileError

Are you sure you have the correct path?

Comment: thx for answer. Yes, it s the correct path. I checked by NSLog. As I said, I do the same with images and it is working with that, but not with the audio file.